# Response.Clear() equivalent in TSQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any equivalent to ASP.NET `Response.Clear()` in TSQL?

On some condition I need to remove the result set from the buffer that was selected earlier.

EDIT:

```
update [ViewCounts] set [SiteViews] += 1  OUTPUT INSERTED.SiteViews 
where  [PageID] = @PageID AND [LastIP] <> @IP


    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN

    --- Need to clear the the empty (OUTPUT INSERTED.SiteViews) buffer here, as it crashes the Entity Framework

    select [SiteViews] from [ViewCounts]  where  [PageID] = @PageID

    END
```

Comment: Have you considered accumulating (prospective) results in a table variable or temporary table?  You can return or delete them as needed after suitable analysis.

Comment: Your question is not quiet clear actually.

Comment: @HABO That's what I do now and it is an awkward way to do it.

Comment: I have never had the need to do that so it would be immensely interesting if you could add a scenario/code where you show how you would use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187762.aspx) to **removes all clean buffers** from the buffer pool.

Comment: A word of caution: do not attempt to execute DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS on a live SQL Server instance 
Whilst DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS is a necessary [first] step in query performance tuning it should NOT be run on a live SQL Server instance which causes the index and data pages flushed from the cache and thus making the next round of DML statements run slower.